# New express not working with PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I followed these docs (https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) I didn't do the install that premakes the files for you. I set up postgres with a table and data. Now I am trying to connect the node server to the database with this new express stuff. This is what I have. Anybody use this new version of express?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
//var db = require('db.sql')
var pgp = require('pg-promise')()
var db = pgp('postgres://postgres:123@localhost/postgres')

db.any('SELECT * FROM Persons')
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('DATA:', data.value)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('ERROR:', error)
  })

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Hello 3000")
})
```

Comment: This is still not working for me

Answer (score 1):

It seems your postgres connection string is wrong. It should be in the format of `postgres://username:password@host:port/database`. Please replace your code as below.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const pgp = require('pg-promise')(/* initialization options */)
const db = pgp('postgres://username:password@host:port/database')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.any('SELECT * FROM Persons')
        .then(data => {
            console.log('DATA:', data)
            return res.status(200).send(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('ERROR:', error)
        })
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Hello 3000')
})
```

Comment: Please replace username, password, host, port and database in the above connection string.

Comment: So I copy pasted it and it doesn't work as soon as I hit localhost in the browser

Comment: Have you changed the above parameters in the connection string?

Comment: yeah, but how can I double check them on postgres?

Comment: Can you please post your connection string here?

Comment: I assume it is postgres://postgres:123@localhost:5432/postgres

Comment: var db = pgp('postgres://gabea:123@localhost/postgres')

Comment: You are missing port. Change connection string to postgres://gabea:123@localhost:5432/postgres

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157173/discussion-between-goyaking-and-chandra-sugur).